# Android OS - Access and play sounds within an app after initiating a phone call

Tags: android, android-intent

I've seen similar question posted, but with no answers.

My question is, after the intent to make a new phone call is initiated, is there anyway to keep the phone call active while accessing sound playbacks within a custom application?

If not, is it possible to modify the phone call activity, so the accessible sounds are in the same interface as the current phonecall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the call active while playing audio in another application, but the caller won't be able to hear it.  It would work like navigation directions while you are on a phone call, you hear them, but not the person on the phone.

You cannot modify the call activity to inject audio into the audio stream of the call, its an Android security measure as far as I know.